# Excel cell referencing

Tags: excel, vba, reference, cell

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have one workbook(book1) with detailed job info. And another workbook(book2) keeping track of only certain details of the job info. Book2 is used to see the running total of all jobs completed so far.

In book2 I have three categories (name, date, income), all can be found in the detailed info in book1. I know how to reference a cell from one workbook to another one (=[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$4)

but to make things easier for me and my co-workers I want to be able to write the name of the job under the "name" category in book2 and use that as that the file name in the formula to locate the referencing book.

I know it sounds confusing so here's and example:

book1

cell G5: $50.00

book2

cell A1(Job Name):book1

cell F7: =[(**A1**).xlsx]Sheet1!$G$5

so in theory it would take the name I inserted into cell A1 and use that as the file name of the Workbook I'm referencing in cell F7. but it doesn't work like that.

If you understand what I'm trying to accomplish, help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the book is open you can use INDIRECT like this:

```
=INDIRECT("'["&A1&".xlsx]Sheet1'!$G$5")
```

This is what my test sheet looks like:

[image]